# Syntax error MySQL IF EXISTS

Tags: mysql, if-statement, subquery

I have SQL query for voting, to check if vote alredy exists, but it keeps giving me syntax error near

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `id` = 298 AND `author` = 'noo
```

Subquery itself runs fine.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `id` = 298 AND `author` = 'noob') THEN
    'exist'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO `votes`(`id`, `author`, `type`, `value`) VALUES (298, "noob", "upvote", 1)
    'upvoted'
END IF
```

Comment: `if else` could only be used in stored functions/procedure and triggers not in standalone sql statements in mysql.

Comment: if your 'id' or 'author' have unique indexes, the you could use INSERT IGNORE or the ON DUPLICATE UPDATE